# How to get vscode to autocomplete "it" instead of "instanceof" for jest for react

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jestjs

In VScode when I type the first few letters of `describe`, the suggestion comes up for `describe` from jest and I pick it and all is good.

[image: react]

When I type `it` for creating a test example there is no suggestion for the jest  `it` and worst of all when I type the two letters "`it`" and the open paren "`(`", instead of

```
it(
```

I get

```
instanceof(
```

so I have to type it, then arrow navigate (left arrow for example) and then right arrow and then i can type the open  paren and that works.

Annoying.

For extensions I have Jest 3.2.0  I don't have other jest plugins, not sure which I would use (there are dozens).

Answer (score 4):

[Jest Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=andys8.jest-snippets) extension overrides this behavior. It also allows to create test template from a snippet.

[image: snippet example]